# Angular2- Polling API created infinite http calls if one gets failed

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I am continuously polling one of my API after every minute,but if any error comes what I observe is API starts getting called in an infinite loop causing my system to hang.
Service:-
    public subscription: Subscription;

```
public _dSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

autorefresh(filterObj) {
    return Observable.timer(60000).subscribe(() => this.callAPI());
}

callAPI() {
    const url = this.endpointURL + '/xyz';

    this.subscription = this.http.post(url, filterObj, this.headerObj)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            let response = res.json();
            return response;
        })
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                this._dSubject.next(response);
            },
            error => (this.handleError(error))
        );
}
```

Component

```
getData(inputData) {

    this.service.callAPI(filterData.filterOptionForRequest);
    this.subscription$ = this.service._dSubject.subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {

      this.service.callAPI(filterData.filterOptionForRequest);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you're trying to use the Observable.timer to make the call every 60 seconds you need to modify it to use 2 arguments. Observable.timer(60000) will wait 60 seconds and then fire and then complete, only having called once. Observable.timer(0,60000) will fire every 60 seconds until you stop it.

Comment: @user2313300 I have called this method again , in my component after the api responds i.e. this.service._dSubject.subscribe(res => {}) i have again called it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like this:

```
 Observable.interval(60000)
                .switchMap(() => this.http.post(url).retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(60000)))
.map((response) => response.text())
            .subscribe();
```